# Form a matrix (a^|i-j|) of dimension 100x100 in R

Tags: r

How to form a matrix (a^|i-j|) of dimension 100x100 in R? similar as
matrix(vector, nrow = 100, ncol = 100)

Comment: a = 0.1 but dimension is 100x100

Comment: Not clear.  Do you have initial matrix of `2 * 4`

Comment: I don't have any initial matrix.  I wish to form a 100x100 matrix whose (i,j) entry is (0.1)^|i-j|.

Comment: I posted a solution below.  I guess that may be what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

We can use `outer`

```
m1 <- outer(1:100, 1:100, FUN = function(i, j) 0.1^abs((i-j)))
dim(m1)
#[1] 100 100
```

---

Or another option is `sapply`

```
m2 <- 0.1^(sapply(1:100, function(i) abs(i - 1:100)))
all.equal(m1, t(m2))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I don't think that `abs(a^(i-j))` is equal to `a^abs(i-j)`, mathematically in general cases

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice.index` like:

```
x  <- matrix(NA_real_, 100, 100)
x <- 0.1^abs((slice.index(x, 1) - slice.index(x, 2)))
```

Comment: I guess it should be `abs((slice.index(x, 1) - slice.index(x, 2)))`, according to OP description

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Oh yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to create such a matrix with `outer()`

```
M <- (a<-0.1)**abs(outer(1:100,1:100,"-"))
```